# how to solve [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run

Tags: testng

Since i'm a beginner in TestNG. Here i'm trying to run 3 methods and i'm deliberately failing the method test2() and test3() so when i run this code i'm getting the message like "[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run"

I'm Running this test within IDE and not in maven command line

Here i'm attaching the structure of my project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBbI0.png)

**Here is my TestNG code:**

```java
package priority;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGRetryFailed {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("i am insde test 1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("i am insde test 2");
        int i=1/0;
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("i am insde test 3");
        Assert.assertTrue(0>1);
    }
}
```

**here is the message what i'm getting in my console:**

```
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage:  [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -configfailurepolicy
      Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
    -d
      Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount
      Number of threads to use when running data providers
    -excludegroups
      Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
    -groups
      Comma-separated list of group names to be run
    -junit
      JUnit mode
      Default: false
    -listener
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener 
      or ISuiteListener
    -methods
      Comma separated of test methods
      Default: []
    -methodselectors
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
    -mixed
      Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with 
      appropriate runner
      Default: false
    -objectfactory
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing 
      ITestRunnerFactory 
    -parallel
      Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
      Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none, true, false]
    -port
      The port
    -reporter
      Extended configuration for custom report listener
    -suitename
      Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or 
      source code
    -suitethreadpoolsize
      Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
      Default: 1
    -testclass
      The list of test classes
    -testjar
      A jar file containing the tests
    -testname
      Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source 
      code 
    -testnames
      The list of test names to run
    -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
      The factory used to create tests
    -threadcount
      Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
    -usedefaultlisteners
      Whether to use the default listeners
      Default: true
    -log, -verbose
      Level of verbosity
    -xmlpathinjar
      The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if 
      -testjar was specified)
      Default: testng.xml
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: @Saheb i'm running as TestNG suite

Comment: @Fayaz - Edit your question and add details on how are you running the tests. Are they from within an IDE or via maven command line. What does your suite look like ? Add snippet of that. Also add a screenshot of how your project structure looks like.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan i have edited my question with screenshot of my project and im running within an IDE and please let me know is that enough?

Comment: Seems like IDE is not properly configured to run the test cases. Can you share the run/debug configurations you are using in the eclipse?